# Question: Is This a Proposition?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

> Every positive even integer can be written as the sum of two primes.

The answer is: this is a proposition. Nobody knows its truth value, but it's unique.

I wonder what is unique and why its uniqueness makes this statement a proposition.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A small point is that $2$ can't be written as a sum of two primes, so your statement is not currently correct. However, if you change it to be for every even integer $\gt 2$, then you have the strong version of [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture).

Comment: I think it must mean that the truth value is unique.  That seems like an odd way of putting it, at least to me.  I would say the truth value is well-defined, (though we don't know what it is.)

Comment: What is your definition of proposition? I am asking because even in philosophy, there is no final consensus on what a proposition is. What is the definition of proposition that you have been given?

Comment: The idea that a proposition is "something that has a truth value" is an informal heuristic. In mathematical logic, a proposition is a purely syntactic object: a well-formed sentence in a well-defined formal language. Truth values only arise when we consider propositions in the context of [models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory).

Answer (score -2):

The term unique is misused here. I'm not certain what term would be the best, but they are trying to convey the following : "the proposition is either true or false, it cannot be both".

A proposition must have a truth value. The proposition showed definitely has a truth value, while we don't know which one, it doesn't change the fact that it has one. Therefore it is a proposition

Answer (score -2):

> Every even integer greater than $~2~$ can be expressed as the sum of two primes.

This is called **Goldbach's conjecture** which is **one of the oldest and best-known unsolved problems** in number theory and all of mathematics.

The conjecture has been shown to hold for all integers less than $~4 × 10^{18}~$, but remains unproven despite considerable effort.

**Note:** In mathematics, a **conjecture** is a **conclusion** or **proposition** based on incomplete information, for which no proof or disproof has yet been found.

*So you can conclude that this statement is a proposition.*

---

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture)

Comment: fyi, the OP does not actually cite the goldbach conjecture.

Comment: Yes, but his/her statement is incomplete as $2$ can not be written as a sum of two primes. If we include this point, then it becomes Goldbach's conjecture.  @RyRytheFlyGuy

Comment: it's not incomplete. it's a complete statement that happens to be false for reasons you just mentioned.